# How to retrieve data from firebase v9 to display it on the frontend?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Hi I have a contact form that I connected to firebase. Now I want to be able to use that data and display in the browser. I tried so many approaches but to no avail. So now I'm seeking your help.

the collection is called **messages**

Here's the code of how I connected the contact form to firebase:

```
import {addDoc, collection} from '@firebase/firestore'
import {db} from '../firebase'

    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
    const [company, setCompany] = useState("")
    const [service, setService] = useState("")
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("")

        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), {
            Email: email,
            Nom: fullName,
            Message: msg,
            Service: service,
            Téléphone: phone,
            Société: company
        })
```

Here is my attempt at retrieving the data from firebase:

```
import { db } from "../firebase"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import {
    onSnapshot,
    collection,
} from "@firebase/firestore"

const messages = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

    useEffect(() =>
        onSnapshot(collection(db, "messages"),
            (snapshot) => {
        setMessages(snapshot.docs)
            }
        ),
            [db]
      )


    return (
        <div>
            {messages.map((message) => {
                <div>
                    <h1>{message.Email}</h1>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default messages
```

Answer (score 3):

I think mostly you're not unwrapping the `data()` from the `DocumentSnapshot` in your `onSnapshot` handler. If that's indeed the only problem (it's hard to be certain with some more details, such as seeing what your documents look like), it'd be fixed with:

```
(snapshot) => {
  setMessages(
    snapshot.docs.map(doc => { 
      return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() } 
    }) 
  )
}
```

Comment: it worked. Wow, Thank you.

Comment: So, when I console.log(messages) I get an array of objects with the data inside. But when I try to display them. it doesn't show. I don't know why.

Comment: when I try ``` <p>{message.Email}</p> ``` nothing shows but when I console.log() it it gives the correct value

Comment: As said, it's hard to be certain what happens without seeing your documents - so I recommend editing your question and showing that. While you're at it, you might also want to *add* the updated code.